# Approve Form submit

Tags: php, mysql

I have trouble with creating an approval form as am still php beginner,

the idea is

user submit a form am setting a default value"0" in the approved row at the table..

so behind the scenes the admin shows all members from this table where approved="0"

and this is the code

```
<code> 

    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","ebarea_epic","...");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ebarea_epic", $con);

$query = "select * from medicalrep where approved='0'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Mobile </th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Faculty</th>
<th>Graduation Year</th>
<th>Region</th>
<th>Area</th>
<th>Line</th>
<th>Appointment Date</th>
<th>Resign Data</th>
<th>Job Title</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Mobile'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Faculty'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Graduation Year'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Region'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Line'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Area'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Appointment'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Resign'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['job_title'] . "</td>";  
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</code>
```

I just want to add checkbox for every table user and when checked thier status changed to 1 in approved column

thanks all

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: lol, what is the actual question?

Comment: I just want to add checkbox for every table user and when checked thier status changed to 1 in approved column 

thanks all

Comment: Create a column in the database. By default put 0 as non approved, 1 as proved. In the admin panel, create form for each post. And accordingly, update the approve column to 1 for each entry checked. You can also ajax. Lots of ways you can accomplish this. If you can't write the code for this, let me know. I'l post the codes as answer.

Comment: It would be great Itachi if you post this codes :) Million thanks !

and yes i did a row in my sql where default value is 0 but the problem is in how to create the form and update the user status :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","ebarea_epic","...");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ebarea_epic", $con);

$query = "select * from medicalrep where approved='0'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$i = 1; //counter for the checkboxes so that each has a unique name
echo "<form action='process.php' method='post'>"; //form started here
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Mobile </th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Faculty</th>
<th>Graduation Year</th>
<th>Region</th>
<th>Area</th>
<th>Line</th>
<th>Appointment Date</th>
<th>Resign Data</th>
<th>Job Title</th>
<th>Update</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Mobile'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Faculty'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Graduation Year'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Region'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Line'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Area'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Appointment'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Resign'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['job_title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[$i]' value='".$row['ID']."'/>";   
  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='approve' value='approve'/>";
echo "</form>";

mysql_close($con);
```

Now comes process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['approve'])){
                if(isset($_POST['check'])){
                    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value){
                        $sql = "UPDATE post SET post_approved = 1 WHERE ID = $value"; //write this query according to your table schema
                        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                    }
                }
            }
```

### **though you are using mysql_* functions here, i recommend you to use** [PDO](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html)

**EDIT:**

As per your request, this is the update.

Change this code in your admin panel script:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='approve' value='approve'/>";
```

Delete the above line and add this instead:

```
echo "<input class='action' type='button' name='approve' value='approve' />";
   echo "<input class='action' type='button' name='edit' value='edit' />";
   echo "<input class='action' type='button' name='delete' value='delete' />";
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='' id='action' />"; //Action (edit, approve or delete) will be set here which will be passed as POST variable on form submission
```

Now you will need some javascript to do some tricks.

Add the following code preferably head section in your admin panel script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.action').click(function(){
                    var action = $(this).attr('name');
                    $('#action').val(action);
                    $(this).closest('form').submit();

                })
            })
     </script>
```

Now comes the modification in process.php file

```
if (isset($_POST['approve'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value) {
            $sql = "UPDATE post SET post_approved = 1 WHERE ID = $value"; //write this query according to your table schema
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
} elseif(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    //do the edit things here
} elseif(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM post WHERE ID=$value";//modify it
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

You may not want to mutiple checkbox for edit. You just need to tweak the javascript code above a little and it'l send the ID as a post variable on form submission from which you can retreive the details for one entry and then edit functions will come. I'l leave it to you. try it, post your trial code here and i'l give you a solution if it doesn't work.

Comment: WOHOOOOOOOOOOOW !! THUMBS UP MAN !! :D 

Could you please tell me if possible to add edit button or delete button beside approve as to either edit the form or delete it and how ?

sorry for bothering but am pretty sure you are talented and professional ... Thanks in ADVANCE :)